# Does Stack Overflow use a parent/child or nested mappings for Elasticsearch?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, search

Does Stack Overflow use a parent/child or nested mapping structure for its Elasticsearch documents?

For example, comments could be nested objects within a question or have a parent and child relationship.

Comment: Not sure about the close votes but I think it is a fair question and can be asked here. If it gets closed migrate it to MSE.

Comment: Questions about the software used on SO are valid. Please don't close.

Comment: What is "elasticsearch" in this context? The search server based on Lucene?

Comment: @Peter It was Lucene. But SE search has been elasticsearch for almost 2 years now. [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)

Comment: ElasticSearch _is_ Lucene inside.

Comment: I can't edit, but the proper name is Elasticsearch, if someone wishes to correct it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We currently do not use a parent/child relationship for Elasticsearch documents. We index questions and the answers to said questions as individual documents right now. We're investigating a nested relationship of 1 question + N answers per document, and may test this in the near future.

One possible problem introduced by nested document structure is the TF / IDF frequency increase of the terms searched upon (which are likely to appear in both question and answers). This would change relevance quite a bit.